# Drawing semi-transparent vesica pisces

Tags: processing

How may I draw a filled semi-transparent [vesica pisces](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/VesicaPiscis_1000.gif)?

The semi-transparent requirement makes overlaying two arc() objects fail.

EDIT:

FTR, answer #1 with extraneous circles removed:

```java
  void draw(){
  background(255);

  fill(0,128);
  noStroke();
  //fudged values vesica pisces using two arcs
  arc(35,50,50,50,-HALF_PI * .5,HALF_PI * .5,OPEN);
  arc(70.5,50,50,50,PI-HALF_PI * .5,PI+HALF_PI * .5,OPEN);
  }
```

outputs this:

[image]

Comment: Instead of downvoting George's excellent answer, why don't you reply with a comment explaining exactly what the answer doesn't work in your context?

Comment: I think it's the line down the middle. If the focus of the question is on transparency I've answered that. The line down the middle is because I used hard coded values rather than using values obtained from correct vesica pisces formula calculation, so odds are either the x position or the arc angles are ever so slightly off. If the question is about correctly calculating these values, this needs to be make clear in the question in the first place and ideally demonstrate even an attempt at trying to tackle the problem so others can advise/support accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent [fill()](http://processing.org/reference/fill_.html) for semi-transparency: either a `(gray,alpha)` or an `(r,g,b,alpha)` sequence. Here's a very very basic example:

```
background(0);
noStroke();

//transparent fill
fill(255,128);
ellipse(35,50,50,50);
ellipse(65,50,50,50);
```

demo:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100,100);
  
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  
  //transparent fill
  fill(255,128);
  ellipse(35,50,50,50);
  ellipse(65,50,50,50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you work out your values based on the vesica pisces proportions (which I'll leave as an excercise to you), you can use `arc()` as well if you want:

```
void draw(){
  background(255);

  //circles
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(35,50,50,50);
  ellipse(70.5,50,50,50);

  fill(0,128);
  noStroke();
  //fudged values vesica pisces using two arcs
  arc(35,50,50,50,-HALF_PI * .5,HALF_PI * .5,OPEN);
  arc(70.5,50,50,50,PI-HALF_PI * .5,PI+HALF_PI * .5,OPEN);

}
```

demo:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(100,100);
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  //circles
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(35,50,50,50);
  ellipse(70.5,50,50,50);
  
  fill(0,128);
  noStroke();
  //fudged values vesica pisces using two arcs
  arc(35,50,50,50,-HALF_PI * .5,HALF_PI * .5,OPEN);
  arc(70.5,50,50,50,PI-HALF_PI * .5,PI+HALF_PI * .5,OPEN);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Turns out you can get pretty close with [TweakMode](http://galsasson.com/tweakmode/) (press mouse for full shape preview):

```
void setup(){
  size(400,400,FX2D);
}
void draw(){

  background(255);

  fill(0,64);
  noStroke();

  float diameter = width / 2;
  float radius   = diameter / 2;

  float x = width / 3.0; 

  arc(x         ,diameter,diameter,diameter,5.231,7.333,OPEN);
  arc(x + radius,diameter,diameter,diameter,2.097,4.184,OPEN);

  if(mousePressed){
    stroke(0);
    line(x,diameter,x+radius,diameter);
    ellipse(x         ,diameter,diameter,diameter);
    ellipse(x + radius,diameter,diameter,diameter);
  }
}
```

**Update** same principles as throughout the answer, just using the 60 degrees increments:

```
void drawFishBladder(float x,float y,float r){
  arc(x - r * 0.5,y,r * 2, r * 2,radians(-60),radians(60),OPEN);
  arc(x + r * 0.5,y,r * 2, r * 2,radians(120),radians(240),OPEN);
}
```

[image: vesica pisces - fish bladder, tomato,tomata]

and demo:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
  background(0,0,100);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  fill(frameCount % 360,100,100);
  drawFishBladder(mouseX,mouseY,map(sin(frameCount * 0.1),-1.0,1.0,20,200));
}
function drawFishBladder(x,y,r){
  arc(x - r * 0.5,y,r * 2, r * 2,radians(-60),radians(60),OPEN);
  arc(x + r * 0.5,y,r * 2, r * 2,radians(120),radians(240),OPEN);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If this isn't the awesomest fish bladder you've ever seen, I don't know what is, seriously.